# Mailer Issue: An error occurred while processing your request. ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mailer

If I use this mailer method, I get the error shown below:

> An error occurred while processing your request

This is my mailer method used in controller ActionResult.

```
   private void SendActivationEmail(string activationCodes, string emailid, string Fullname)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminFromEmailAddress"].ToString());
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailid);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        string LinkPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["verifyuserpath"].ToString();
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string strBody;
        int a = 0;
        strBody = "";
        strBody = strBody + "Dear" + " " + Fullname + "," + "<br><br>";
        strBody = strBody + "Thank you for your interest in the testing Program." + "<br><br>";
        strBody = strBody + "Please click <a href=" + LinkPath + "Registers/IAActivation?emailId=" + emailid + "&uCode=" + activationCodes + "&type=" + a + ">here</a> to finish setting up this testing account, we just need to make sure this email address is yours  or paste the following link into your browse" + "<br><br>";
        strBody = strBody + "<a href=" + LinkPath + "Registers/IAActivation?emailId=" + emailid + "&uCode=" + activationCodes + "&type=" + a + ">" + LinkPath + "Registers/IAActivation?emailId=" + emailid + "&uCode=" + activationCodes + "&type=" + a + "" + "</a><br><br>";
        strBody = strBody + "<br>With Regards" + "," + "<br>";
        strBody = strBody + "testing Team";
        message.Subject = "Verification Mail";
        message.Body = strBody;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClientclientPath"].ToString());
        client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpClientclientPathPort"].ToString());
        client.Send(message);
   }
```

This is my app setting calling from web.config mailer paths.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

    <add key="AdminFromEmailAddress" value="info@xyz.in" />
    <add key="SmtpClientclientPath" value="000.0.0.1" /> 
    <add key="SmtpClientclientPathPort" value="25" />
    <!-- Your SMTP Server IP  -->
    <add key="gmailHost" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="userName" value="techhelp@xyz.in" />
    <add key="password" value="tech@123" />
    <add key="gmailport" value="587" />
    <add key="verifyuserpath" value="http://xyz.in/" />
</appSettings>
```

If I comment out this line

```
client.Send(message);
```

in the mailer method, then registration submission working but mailer is not going.

Actually I am new into asp.net mvc5 but mailer path as I declare same like web forms. Please help me to out this mailer issue. And I did not publish the my mvc5 project directly uploaded all files into live without publish.

Comment: What's the full error text?

Comment: Is your SMTP client path correct?

Comment: Error is coming on page:error An error occurred while processing your request. @stuartd

Comment: Ya that correct same path i used in my old web forms application and web form application is running now. @RichardHubley

Comment: You're going to have to find out what the actual error is to fix this.

Comment: when i will comment this line:  client.Send(message); and then submission happening and when i will uncomment this line error is comming, i know its mailer error. @stuartd

Comment: I did not publish my application uploaded into live all files. I want to know is my mailer method and app setting is correct. @stuartd

Comment: An exception must be getting thrown by the mailer. You will have to Catch it and display it on screen in order to debug further.

Comment: normally for MVC I publish the application, the code files get compiled into a dll only the Views are sent to the server as files. I'm not sure if you can just file copy directly to server from your code.

Comment: if i will add exception then it will show na in my web page? because i am not able to finding anything in event log. @RichardHubley

Comment: directly adding files also working the site and i register my website and inserting into my db server and check i want to know mailer method is correct? and app setting is correct because this type of setting given into my old web forms. @RichardHubley

Comment: You are sure you are using the right value since you have both  `gmailHost` and `SmtpClientclientPath`. Post back when you can provide the Error Message.

Comment: actually i added this app setting same as one of my old asp.net web forms live working mailer. but this is mvc project so getting confused, i want to know if i will keep try catch then it will show exact error, as you telling i have to check value of gmailhost and smtclientclientpath values. @RichardHubley

Comment: means you are saying i have to use any of one   SmtpClientclientPath or gmailHost. @RichardHubley

Comment: Reason for downvote, the person who did down May be he did not understand question.

Comment: I did not down vote but without the error message no one can help you, and it doesn't help anyone else

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your SmtpClient Like following :

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("fromAddress", "fromPassword"),
    Timeout = 20000
};
```

Replace the FromAddress and Password.

**NOTE** : Don't forget to enable *"Allow Less Secure Apps"* on your Google's Account Security Settings.

Comment: how can i add strBody please update full answer and my mailer method is wrong? .@Nirmal Subedi

Comment: You need to replace your SmtpClient initialization line, everything else are same!

Comment: Your means i do not call from app setting directly use in mailer method, is working sample which you are using in live application?. @Nirmal Subedi

Comment: my from address is not gmail, its one of company email id. @Nirmal Subedi

Comment: I saw your app-settings and you are using smtp.gmail.com! 
I took that from my own Working application hosted in ASP.NET Core to send Email to clients.

Comment: I didn't said put all your settings inside the code not in app settings. I gave you the code sample now you can replace the values to take from your app settings rather than hard coding there.

Comment: ok i will check and update you and now my office if off i have upload these files into live then only i can update my answer. @Nirmal